# Shell execute multiple commands from string with ampersand(background process)

Tags: shell

It seems that sh do not treat `;` as delimiter of command.

```
$ sh -c 'nohup ./server &; echo foo'
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

So, how to execute multiple commands from string with ampersand(background process)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are after is what is called [Asynchronous lists](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_02):

> If a command is terminated by the control operator <ampersand> ( `&` ), the shell shall execute the command asynchronously in a subshell. This means that the shell shall not wait for the command to finish before executing the next command.
>
> The format for running a command in the background is:
>
> ```
> command1 & [command2 & ... ]
> ```
>
> **<sub>source: [POSIX.1-2017](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_02)</sub>**

The following example shows this behaviour:

```
sh -c "{ sleep 10 && echo foo ;} & echo bar"
```

This will execute `echo bar` and after 10 seconds, `echo foo` due to the command `sleep 10 && echo foo`. The latter is written as a compound command.

Thus, the solution is to remove the semi-column `;` which is actually a [sequential list](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_04). The reason why the original was failing is that you try to execute an empty command. This works:

```
sh -c "echo foo & echo bar ; echo car"
```

but this fails:

```
sh -c "echo foo &          ; echo car"
```

as there is syntactically a command missing.

So in the end, the solution is simple:

```
sh -c 'nohup ./server & echo foo'
```